# SwiftUI cuts off Text

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am rewriting the existing UIKit cell using SwiftUI. The problem is `Spacer()` cuts `Text()` and shows less text than the UIKit version (Ethereum C... vs Ethere...). The goal is to have the graph always in the same position in all cells and show more symbols in `Text()`.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: .designSystem(.small)) {
                KFImage(viewModel.tradable.logoURL)
                    .serialize(by: SVGCacheSerializer())
                    .setProcessor(SVGProcessor())
                    .scaleFactor(Layout.scaleFactor)
                    .resizable()
                    .placeholder {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color(viewModel.tradable.placeholderColor == nil ? .gray : UIColor(hex: viewModel.tradable.placeholderColor!)))

                    }
                    .frame(width: Layout.imageWidth, height: Layout.imageHeight)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Layout.imageWidth / 2))
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Layout.imageWidth / 2).stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2 / UIScreen.main.scale))

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .designSystem(.extraSmall3)) {
                    Text(viewModel.name).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.semibold).lineLimit(1)
                    Text(viewModel.symbol).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(Color(ThemeManager.current.neutral50))
                }

                Spacer()

                AssetLineChartViewRepresentable(viewModel: chartViewModel).frame(width: 65, height: 20)

                Spacer()

                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: .designSystem(.extraSmall3)) {
                    percentChangeView(assetPercentChangeType: viewModel.assetPercentChangeType)
                    Text(viewModel.priceString).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(Color(ThemeManager.current.neutral50))

                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing])

            if !viewModel.shouldHideSeparator {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Divider().padding(.leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: Layout.frameHeight)
    .background(
        backgroundView(assetPositionType: viewModel.corners)
    )
}
```

[image]

Removing `Spacer()`

[image]

Comment: I tried, but then the content does not stretch across the whole HStack and there are gaps left and right.

Comment: Your padding may loose space every where. What do you get without on simulator or device (not preview) ?